# TypeError: Invalid argument type while push list to List in Node JS

Tags: node.js, redis

Hey I am getting this error

```
/home/gm/Desktop/ZulfDemo/streamusingws/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/RESP2/encoder.js:17
            throw new TypeError('Invalid argument type');
```

While I am trying to run this script

```
const redis = require("redis");
const redisclient = redis.createClient();

(async () => {
    await redisclient.connect();
})();

console.log("Connecting to the Redis");

redisclient.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Connected!");
});

redisclient.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error in the Connection");
});

const generateRandomNumber = () => {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000); // generate random number between 0 and 100,000
    console.log('Generated random number:', randomNumber); // add this line to check the value of randomNumber
    redisclient.RPUSH(['randomNumbers', randomNumber], (err, reply) => { // store number in Redis list
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error in rPush:', err); // add this line to log any errors
      } else {
        console.log('Stored ' + randomNumber + ' in Redis list');
      }
    });
  }
  
  setInterval(generateRandomNumber, 1000); // generate a random number every second
```

Here i tried with rpush, rPush and all but still getting this error can anyone help m to solve this.

Comment: shouldnt it be like `.RPUSH('randomNumbers', randomNumber, (err...`

Comment: @cmgchess still getting the same

Comment: https://github.com/redis/node-redis/issues/938 this is where i got it

Comment: this gives me rpush is not defined @cmgchess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally got the answer here we have to pass string in all the terms instead of number so I just add toString() after number like this.

```
const generateRandomNumber = () => {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000); // generate random number between 0 and 100,000
    console.log('Generated random number:', randomNumber); // add this line to check the value of randomNumber
    redisclient.RPUSH(['randomNumbers', randomNumber.toString()], (err, reply) => { // store number in Redis list
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error in rPush:', err); // add this line to log any errors
      } else {
        console.log('Stored ' + randomNumber + ' in Redis list');
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the `RPUSH` parameters in an array.  Also with node-redis 4 you don't need to use callbacks, you should use promises instead.

Here's a cleaned up version that shows both of these things:

```
const redis = require("redis");
const redisclient = redis.createClient();

(async () => {
    await redisclient.connect();
})();

console.log("Connecting to the Redis");

redisclient.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Connected!");
});

redisclient.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error in the Connection");
});

const generateRandomNumber = async () => {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000); // generate random number between 0 and 100,000
    console.log("Generated random number:", randomNumber); // add this line to check the value of randomNumber
    try {
      await redisclient.RPUSH("randomNumbers", `${randomNumber}`);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error pushing to Redis:");
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
  
  setInterval(generateRandomNumber, 1000);
```

Output from running this:

```
$ node index.js
Connecting to the Redis
Connected!
Generated random number: 69258
Generated random number: 15338
Generated random number: 45459
Generated random number: 79371
Generated random number: 89456
Generated random number: 60289
^C
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> lrange randomNumbers 0 -1
1) "69258"
2) "15338"
3) "45459"
4) "79371"
5) "89456"
6) "60289"
```

If you use a module, you won't need the IIFE either as you can use top level `await` if your Node version is newer.  So this could be further simplified by adding `"type":"module"` in your `package.json`:

```
import { createClient } from "redis";
const redisclient = createClient();

await redisclient.connect();
console.log("Connected to Redis.");

const generateRandomNumber = async () => {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
  console.log("Generated random number:", randomNumber);
  try {
    await redisclient.RPUSH("randomNumbers", `${randomNumber}`);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error pushing to Redis:");
    console.log(e);
  }
}
  
setInterval(generateRandomNumber, 1000);
```